# Can I put multiple words in a list, with "-que" on the last one?

Tags: classical-latin, enclitic

As a sort of followup to [Are "-que" and "et" equivalent?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1/11), I'd like to know if this would be considered a valid construction (in [classical-latin](/questions/tagged/classical-latin)):

> Arma virum navesque cano

(modified version of [Virgil's *Aeneid*, I.1](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Aeneis/Liber_I#0))

Are there any examples of classical Latin authors 'stringing together' more than two objects with a single `-que` suffix? If so, is this the correct way to form it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is acceptable practice.  Allen and Greenough cite three examples from Cicero in [§323](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q7cAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA199):

> voce voltu motuque (Brut. 110), *by voice, expression, and gesture.*
>
> curam consilium vigilantiamque (Phil. vii. 20), *care, wisdom, and vigilance.*
>
> quorum auctoritatem dignitatem voluntatemque defenderas (Fam. i. 7. 2), *whose dignity, honor, and wishes you had defended.*

That's Cicero's *Brutus de Claris Oratoribus*, *Philippicae*, and *ad Familiares*.