# Latin ligature "qz"?

Tags: spelling, typography, ligatures

I'm wondering what is that ligature:

[image]

The closest on the [Wikipedia's list of ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) would be "qp" but it doesn't look exactly like that.

Answer (score 15):

I would say that is a common abbreviation for "*-que*". Maybe you could find useful Cappelli's [Dizionario di Abbreviature latine](http://www.hist.msu.ru/Departments/Medieval/Cappelli/) (a very detailed repertory of latin abbreviations). Take a look [here](http://www.hist.msu.ru/Departments/Medieval/Cappelli/CPLLI300.HTM).

Here is the phrase with the soluted words:

> *silensq(ue) sisto tuumq(ue)*

I would add that this is not a ligature but an **abbreviation**, while -st- of the word *sisto* could be properly defined as a ligature.

Comment: And since it's not a ligature, the relevant Wikipedia article is not [Typographic ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature), but [Scribal abbreviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation), which includes this: "…the Arabic numeral 3-like mark ꝫ [was] generally at the end of a word on the baseline…. After q, [it] form[s] the conjunction -que…"

Answer (score 7):

It must be *que*.
The conjunction *-que* is very common in Latin, and it is no surprise it has it's own symbol.
For example *suumque* is ([almost](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1/79)) the same as *et suum* and means "and his own".
The excerpt you have is a fragment, and the exact translation depends on more context.

Answer (score 4):

q + U+0301 (combining acute accent) + U+A76B (et sign) using hlig on all three characters will give you:

[image: q + U+0301 (combining acute accent) + U+A76B (et sign)]

This combination will appear in Junicode Two (github.com/psb1558/Junicode-font).

Comment: https://github.com/psb1558/Junicode-font

Answer (score 3):

For me this is the Unicode Private Use Area character U+E8BF    LATIN SMALL LETTER Q LIGATED WITH FINAL ET defined by a [Medieval Unicode Font Initiative](https://mufi.info/) recommendation, however the diacritical mark over the character is a mystery for me.

Comment: See the answers above – this is a common scribal abbreviation for _-que_.

Comment: @gmvh The original poster haven't explicitely asked for the meaning of it, he explictely asked what kind of ligature it is. My answer doesn't contradict yours but supplement it.