# Multaque as a standalone word?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm finding that *multaque* is translated in multiple different ways.

- Several sources say there is no translation at all
- One translates it as "attacking" (Google Translate, yes)
- Some translate it as "cooperative"
- Finally several translate it as "many that..." or "many who..." as a lead in to a sentence or clause.

Any input, or can it be all of the above depending on the context? I know the individual meanings of each, and am just trying to figure out the most likely meaning(s) when connected. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers. That's pretty much the conclusion I reached, but the automatic translators often respond also to human feedback which led me to wonder if there was something obscure missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are using an *automatic translator* instead of a dictionary. Spoiler alert: **There is not a single good automatic translator for Latin.**

For this kind of task, you should use a dictionary: take a look at [Which online Latin dictionaries should I use and why?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why) for information about which to pick.

"Multaque" is a combination of *multa* and the enclitic *-que*.

- *Multa* is either the feminine singular nominative (or ablative, if multā) or neuter plural nominative/accusative of the adjective [*multus, -a, -um*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmultus), which means "much/many." It can also be the noun *multa*, as pointed out in Joonas's answer.
- *-que* simply means "and"

***Multaque* doesn't mean anything in particular outside of its context.** It is as meaningful/meaningless as English, "And much." Here is an example of it used in context, along with its translation:

> **Multaque** in ea genera ferarum nasci constat, quae reliquis in locis visa non sint... (Caesar, *De Bello Gallico* 6.25.5)

Translation:

> **And** it is well known that **many** kinds of beasts are born in it [Germany], which have not been seen in other places.

Comment: Good answer! (I'm glad that I'm the one to beat someone else by 14 seconds this time.)

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with a standalone word *multaque*.
I believe it is *multa* and the enclitic *-que*, meaning ([roughly](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1/79)) the same as *et multa*.

The word *multa* can mean several things:

- [much (adjective)](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2037166)
- [much (adverb)](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1010263)
- [penalty](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2037071)
- [punish (imperative)](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2037163)

Without further context, I would translate *multaque* as "and many".
But details of the answer depend on details of the question.
I found no support for any sense of attacking or cooperation, but I may have missed something.