# How would you translate the title "A Song of Ice and Fire" into Classical Latin?

Tags: preposition, genitive

I've seen "Carmen Glaciei Ignisque", but I have some doubt with the use of genitive here.

Can someone help me find examples from classical works that support the use of genitive?

Or find an explanation in a grammar book, since I can't seem to find a fitting one. It's not possessive genitive, partitive, genitive of quality, of material...

Do you think "Carmen de Glacie Igneque" will work?

---

Stuff I've found so far:
*I'm not sure about the date, since I guess titles may be added a lot later, and some are for Greek works.

Titles:

Carmen de Duobus Populis
Carmen De Moribus

Carmen Fratrum Arvalium (performed by Fratres Arvales)
Carmen Saliorum (performed by Salii)
Carmen Naupactium (attributed to a Naupactus)

*Carmen Nelei (about Neleus)
"In Carmine Priami quod est" (probably about Priamus) - Varro
"et in Nelei Carmine" - Varro

It looks like Nelei Carmine/Carmen Nelei supports using genitive.

---

Another pro genitive:
"ut a Naeuio narratum est in carmine belli Punici"

I think I have enough reason to believe it's OK to use genitive in this case, although I have the feeling that these authors chose genitive for a shorter and more concise name to refer to a work, also more casual perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

Consider these classical titles:

- Commentarii de bello Gallico (Caesar)
- Commentarii de bello civili (Caesar)
- De inventione (Cicero)
- De oratore ad Quintum fratrem libri tres (Cicero)
- De re publica (Cicero)

Using the preposition *de* to denote the topic of a work is the typical choice in classical Latin.
The best option alongside *de* is to use an adjective: *carmen de glacie* and *carmen glaciale* are not exactly identical but both worth considering.

As you have found, *carmen* is a good word for a song.

I recommend taking a look at [this site's very first question about the difference between *et* and *-que*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1/79).
In this case *-que* is indeed a good choice.

It seems to me that the word *ignis* has two attested singular ablatives: *igni* and *igne*.
As a brief classical corpus study shows both (although it might be a matter of later editorial choices), both are perfectly fine.
Cairnavon pointed out in a comment that the original ablative *igni* is mostly reserved for rare special uses in classical Latin and the general ablative is *igne* — in light of this your choice of *igne* is indeed better.

The best choice depends on what "of" means in "of ice and fire".
If it means topic ("about ice"), then *de* is the best choice.
If it means type ("like ice", "made of ice", "icy"), then an adjective or indeed the genitive will work.
You can think of the genitive of material, either literally or figuratively.

In conclusion, you suggestion *Carmen de glacie igneque* works well, and you may want to consider variations such as *Carmen de glacie ignique* and *Carmen glaciale igneumque* and *Carmen glaciei ignisque*.

Comment: Originally all i-stems had an abl. sg. in *-i* and consonant stems had *-e*, but by the Classical period analogy had extended the consonant stem forms to the i-stems except for i-stems with an acc. sg. in *-im* and a handful of others. *Ignis* retained the old ending some common expressions (*ferro ignique*, *aqua et igni interdicere*), so both forms coexisted; I think the average contemporary grammarian would prescribe using *igne* outside of those expressions, though.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Thanks! I updated the answer regarding the ablative ending.

Comment: Thanks! I thought of adjectives too, but for ice and fire, I found them (with no reason) too specifically suggesting 'icy and fiery'. I just updated some thoughts at the end of my question, what do you think?

Comment: @杨Eugene I expanded my answer to discuss the genitive too. It depends on what kind of an "of" you want to have. Let me know if that was unclear.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Do you mean the part about "like ice"? Is it Genitive of Material?

Comment: @杨Eugene Yes, I mean a genitive of material. But it can also be understood figuratively, so that it means "icy" or "ice-like". I will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The genitive is fine (carmen amoris, fabula amoris, etc.; I personally couldn't care less what anybody would like to call that genitive).
My own preference here would be with et or atque instead of -que: Carmen glaciei et/atque ignis.
The option with de is not wrong (carmen de bello Troiano),  it just strikes me as a bit too formal in this context.

Comment: But if I'm not mistaken, those aren't classical works. So far I've found Carmen de Duobus Populis, Carmen De Moribus through google. I only found Carmen Fratrum Arvalium, but to me it sounds like it implies that's a song made or sung by Fratres Arvales. I would really like an example from classical works, or to find an explanation in a grammar book, if not all grammarians missed it.

Comment: I didn't cite titles, I cited language. You can, of course, believe me or not.

Comment: Well, languages change. A valid construction for mediaeval or modern speakers may not be valid for the ancient Romans. It'll be much appreciated if you can cite some classical work. The idea that "of" represents is so vague, I don't know how it fits into the list of explanations (possession/quality .. etc.)

Comment: Eugene, you're mistaken, but all I can say is: You're welcome.

Comment: Well, you shared your opinion and I appreciate it, even though I'm looking for more than opinions.

Comment: Eugene, language is not mathematics. But what I said is not opinion, but simply how this particular aspect of Latin works, whether you like it or not. Of course, you can take it or leave it.

Comment: @Batavulus I'm confused: are you denying that there are important differences between classical and medieval Latin? ...or that this particular construction is only attested in the latter?

Comment: You first have to define Classical, then Medieval, then important differences. But anticipating that discussion, I'd say that the differences tend to be exaggerated. As for the genitive in my example, it is fine either way and by no means exclusively medieval.