# Does -que get appended to adjectives?

Tags: classical-latin

For example in the following sentence should the adjective 'magnus' also take 'que' to agree with the noun 'puer'?

Puella puerque magnus.

Comment: Think of *Senatus Populusque Romanus* (SPQR).

Comment: Yes. _-que_ is what modern grammarians call a [clitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic): it attaches to whichever word is in its favoured position, irrespective of the grammatical function of the word. An example in English is the possessive _'s_, which attaches to the last word in a noun phrase. Typically this will be a noun (_the man's hat_), but it can be a noun which is not the possessor (_the king of Spain's daughter_) and at least for some speakers it can be a word in the phrase which is not  a noun (_the guy I used to work with's hat_ - awkward in writing, but people say it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Treat it not like a form of the noun, but a separate word that gets attached at the end. It functions just like *et* except it goes after, not before the word.

See [this thread](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-que-and-et-equivalent) for more information.

Note that *-que* gets attached to the next word it conjoins. You could have also written *puella magnusque puer* and it would have been correct still. Thus in Cato we read:

> de omnibus agris optimoque loco...
> Concerning all the fields and the best place...